# Wordpress index.php: Show div just when site contains 6 posts

Tags: wordpress, themes

In my wordpress index.php i need to know if the page has enough posts (more than 6) that the pagination is active or not and when the pagination is active i want to show a DIV Element.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of posts in your query using [$post_count](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties). For example:

```
<?php 
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    $post_count = $the_query->post_count;

    if ( $post_count > 6 ) {
        // Show the div here...
    }
?>
```

Read more [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties).